# How to fetch text from a TextView in xml file to a TexView in a custom dialog?

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView in my `.xml file` and below that TextView I have a button. The text in TextView changes everytime when the app is running. I created a custom dialog so that when I press the button the custom dialog shows. In this custom dialog I also have a TextView and I want this TextView to take and dislplay data that is in my main TextView.

Here is my `main.xml file`

```
<TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="country"/>
```

And this is TextView in `custom_dialog.xml file`

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/get_country"
        android:text=""/>
```

Below is my `MainActivity.class` custom dialog in `onCreate()`

```
customDialog= new Dialog( this );
    customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    customDialog.setCancelable( true );
    TextView textContry=(TextView)customDialog.findViewById(R.id.get_country);
```

I need this TextView in `custom_dialog` to take data in TextView of `main.xml` when the dialog shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set text in custom dialog textView by taking the text from main text view on a button click.

```
    textContry.setText(textviewMain.getText().toString());
```